# How to create a diagonal band in CSS3?

Tags: html, css

How can I can create a band(popular) in CSS3? 
Image sample:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBzwn.jpg

Comment: Questions seeking help ("**why isn't, or how to make, this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary**_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're thinking of are referred to as "CSS ribbons": http://www.cssportal.com/css-ribbon-generator/

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you so much!!